# CSS Font size not rendered by browser

Tags: html, css

I have a php-script that creates a website dynamically from a database. For better readability I want to use two different font sizes, larger for the name, smaller for the date. I read a lot and finally added the "span id" in the output.

```css
#Klein {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class='Liste'><a class='linkz3' href='index_dev.php?gekauft=49'>TK-Pommes&nbsp;<span id="Klein"> 2020-12-22</span></a>
```

When I watch the page in the Firefox inspector, the small font from the CSS is recognized by the browser for the date string within the span tag, but there is no difference in the font size [see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntk59.png)

Since Firefox Linux, Firefox Android and Chrome Android all behave the same, I must have made a mistake. But which?

Comment: Try `font-size: .75em;`

Comment: Yep. So easy. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `1em` is the size of the parent element. In short the advantage of using `em` over `px` is that `em` scales where `px` does not.

So to make it smaller you should try something like:

```css
#Klein
{
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class='Liste'>
  <a class='linkz3' href='index_dev.php?gekauft=49'>
    TK-Pommes&nbsp;
    <span id="Klein"> 2020-12-22</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed. That fixed it. Since the "larger" font was 3em, I was assuming I should see a difference, when using a lower em.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know too much about `em` which you are using as the unit for your font-size. `Em` is similar as `%` and 1em = 100% i.e, it will set its font size equal to the font-size of its parent element which is the `Username` here.

Comment: please leave an upvote and mark as accepted if it helps.

Comment: I have less than 15 so far so it does not show up yet